# Collapsed margin, even width padding or border

Tags: html, margin

So, the problem is about collapsed margin.

Follow this example : http://jsfiddle.net/2ausj/

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">

    <head>
<title>Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, tv, projection" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <div id="home" class="main"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="main"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>​
```

And Css

```
html { overflow: hidden;}

body {
background: transparent url('../images/background.jpg') repeat;
}

#main { background: blue; padding: 1px; border: 1px;}

.main {
max-width: 1000px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
margin: 50px auto;
position: relative;
position: absolute;
}

p { height: 1px; }
```

I have some div. Each have a margin top and bottom of 50px in this case but betwen the divs, there is only 50 px margin instead of 100px

I read lot of articles about collapsing margin, all of them say to set padding or border to the parent. I tried to put div directly in body and set padding to the body, i tried to set padding on my div, i tried to puts my div in a container div and set him padding or border, nothing seem to work.

Only solution i found but it's dirty, as you can see in my example, is put an element betwen div with a 1px height. And then, there is finally 100px betwen divs, even 101 because of 1px

.

I wish a greater solution, and also understand why nothing i've tried is working.

Please excuse my bad english (Not my fault, i'm french) and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your first div has an ID as well as a class you could do this:

Change your `.main` margin to: `margin:0 auto 100px auto;`

And add the `#home` ID with a style of `margin-top:100px;`

I fiddled with the Fiddle for a few and don't understand why the top and bottom margin of 50px isn't working, but what I have provided above will fix your issue.  If this works for you please accept it as answered.

Comment: No sorry you didn't understand : i want 50px margin top and bottom on all my div. it isn't possible to have a div with bottom margin and then a div whit top margin without element betwen ?

Comment: It should be possible, and I don't understand why it isn't working.  Its quite weird.  You couldn also add `padding-top:100px;` to `#main` rather than adding the `#home: margin-top:100px;` style.  Both of these will give you the same result as adding 50 top and 50 bottom to each div.

Comment: No, listen : i want to have top and bottom space for each bloc, not a larger value on divs margin bottom . I found another replacement solution : use padding instead of margin. It's work , i can have padding bottom on a div and padding top on the follower, and i have the right 2 spacing value. But my solution doesn't work i had to set background on divs...